# How to filter results from AWS CLI command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

How can I filter the following so just results with IP starting with 10.* are returned?

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag-value,Values=mytagavalue" --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{InstanceId:InstanceId,PrivateDnsName:PrivateDnsName,State:State.Name, IP:NetworkInterfaces[0].PrivateIpAddress}'
[
    [
        {
            "InstanceId": "i-12345bnmsdfod",
            "PrivateDnsName": "ip-10-34-24-4.my.there.com",
            "State": "running",
            "IP": "10.10.10.4"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "InstanceId": "i-12345bnmsdfop",
            "PrivateDnsName": "",
            "State": "terminated",
            "IP": null
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Option 1) Via Filters

Use the `network-interface.addresses.private-ip-address` filter to select values matching only "10.*", which will match addresses starting with "10.".

```
--filters "Name=network-interface.addresses.private-ip-address,Values=10.*"
```

Simply include a space between different filters to delimit them.

#### Full Example

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag-value,Values=mytagavalue" "Name=network-interface.addresses.private-ip-address,Values=10.*" --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{InstanceId:InstanceId,PrivateDnsName:PrivateDnsName,State:State.Name, IP:NetworkInterfaces[0].PrivateIpAddress}'
```

---

### Option 2) Via Query

Use the JMESPath `starts_with()` function to perform a partial string comparison of "10." against each network interface's private IP address.

#### Step By Step

First, select all instances:

```
Reservations[].Instances[]
```

Then pipe to filter for only instances containing network interfaces that have a private ip address starting with "10.":

```
| [? NetworkInterfaces [? starts_with(PrivateIpAddress, '10.')]]
```

Then select the fields just like you did before. This has not changed. (Note that you may want to select for all network interfaces instead of just the first.)

```
.{InstanceId:InstanceId,PrivateDnsName:PrivateDnsName,State:State.Name, IP:NetworkInterfaces[0].PrivateIpAddress}"
```

#### Full Example

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag-value,Values=mytagavalue" --query "Reservations[].Instances[] | [? NetworkInterfaces [? starts_with(PrivateIpAddress, '10.')]].{InstanceId:InstanceId,PrivateDnsName:PrivateDnsName,State:State.Name, IP:NetworkInterfaces[0].PrivateIpAddress}"
```

---

### Further Reading

- [JMESPath Documentation - starts_with()](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#starts-with)
- [AWS Documentation - Controlling Command Output from the AWS Command Line Interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html)
- [AWS Documentation - Listing and Filtering Using the CLI and API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Filtering.html#Filtering_Resources_CLI)

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted... thanks!  I was missing the '.' separators to path to the nested object value.  Many thanks! :)

Comment: the filter name can be found here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstances.html, they are not always the same as the field names.